# A hack for getting a *capital* Weierstrass P in order to represent the Power Set operation

Tags: typography, math-operators

I've been reading around stack exchange trying to find out how to get the symbol I wanted for the [power set operation in set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).

In my opinion, the best and most standard symbol for this is the capital Weierstrass "P" (not to be confused with the lowercase one used for Weierstrass elliptical functions, which is produced by `\wp` in math mode). As far as I could find, there isn't a capital Weierstrass "P" out there.  Other people have asked the same question, so I thought that I'd post my solution.  I just took the lowercase Weierstrass "p", made it bigger, and raised it. The result is satisfactory:

```
\newcommand{\powerset}{\raisebox{.15\baselineskip}{\Large\ensuremath{\wp}}}

\begin{document}
Weierstrass p: lower, $\wp$, capital $\powerset$    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use it for a while and probably we'll see you here again very soon :) (since it is math font dependent, skip dependent, mathmode dependent, math kerning is wrong etc.)

Comment: `\mathcal{P}` ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In any event, as percusse noted, you may run into issues with this command.

Comment: While it is in no way discouraged to answer your own question, we do encourage a clear separation between question and answer. Your post as it stands now seems to be both. You could move the hack to the answer space or indicate that you want to discuss your solution instead. You might want to consider the common way of denoting the power set of using `\mathcal{P}` as David Carlisle suggests instead.

Comment: Do you mean `\mathfrak{P}` from `\usepackage{amssymb}`? That's what I've seen used before for this.

Comment: `\usepackage{mathscr}` and `\mathscr P` - power sets are just curly P's not the Weierstrass ones.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments! percusse: I'm not sure why there's anything wrong with being math-font/mode dependent.  I originally thought that it should be skip dependent, but now I see why that is wrong.  If you think there's a better way to execute my hack, could you let me know?

Comment: Andrew Swann, I have a feeling that \mathscr P might be acceptable, but I can't find the package on CTAN.

Comment: The “lowercase Weierstraß “p” is really awful, but it's an established symbol for a very specific mathematical object. I have seen the power set denoted with various forms of “P”: normal, calligraphic, script, fraktur; but never with a big “Weierstraß p”. I even saw it denoted with a "B" (for Boolean). Take your pick, but define a macro for it, to begin with: `\newcommand{\pset}{\mathcal{P}}`, so if you change your mind you can simply modify the definition.

Comment: @DeliaRuby You forgot an `@` in front of my name so I didn't get notififed.  In fact I meant `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` for the Ralph Smith formal script fonts which provides a nice `\mathscr`

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a question!

Comment: The solution is to use the explit math symobls. Put the following into your preamble and then you can use `\powerset`: `\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolC}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC}{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC10
  <12->   MnSymbolC12%
}{}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\powerset}{\mathord}{MnSyC}{180}
`

Answer (score 29):

The usual markup for this is `\mathcal{P}` although a script P is also possible`\mathscr` in various versions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\let\euscr\mathscr \let\mathscr\relax% just so we can load this and rsfs
\usepackage[scr]{rsfso}
\newcommand{\powerset}{\raisebox{.15\baselineskip}{\Large\ensuremath{\wp}}}
\begin{document}

$\mathcal{P}(X)$ 

$\euscr{P}(X)$

$\mathscr{P}(X)$

$\powerset(X)$


\bigskip\hrule\bigskip
\tiny

$\mathcal{P}(X)$ 

$\euscr{P}(X)$

$\mathscr{P}(X)$

$\powerset(X)$


\end{document}
```

Comment: There is also the possibility to use the functionality of math font families somehow (I don't understand the details): `\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolC}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC}{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC10
  <12->   MnSymbolC12%
}{}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\powerset}{\mathord}{MnSyC}{180}`. I would have added my own answer, but the question is closed. I did not want to edit your answer, so I just put it here.